# How to go from Hidden state to Collapsed state by swiping up in Android Persistent Bottom Sheet?

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

After dragging the bottom sheet from collapsed state to hidden state , swiping up from the bottom of the screen doesn't open the bottom sheet to the collapsed state which is doable in google map's bottom sheet.
Like this:

[image]
[image]

How to achieve this if that is not a library functionality?

activity_main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- include main content -->
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!-- Adding bottom sheet after main content -->
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

bottom_sheet.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dandelion Chocolate"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

<!--                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:rating="4" />-->

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4.7"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="(51)"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="12 min away"
                 />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:text="740 Valencia St, San Fracisco, CA"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"

        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:text="(415) 349-0942"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:text="Wed, 10 AM - 9 PM"
/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="PROCEED PAYMENT"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DEDEDE"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity's code:

```
private BottomSheetBehavior sheetBehavior;
private LinearLayout bottom_sheet;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottom_sheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet);



    sheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View view, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED: {
                    Log.d("Tag", "Close Sheet");
                }
                break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED: {
                    Log.d("Tag", "Expand Sheet");
                }
                break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can I see what your layout looks like?
Are you using ConstraintLayout Or CoordinatorLayout ?

Comment: I'm adding the layouts. I've used CoordinatorLayout .

Comment: I'm sure you're seeing what you missed in the LinearLayout? if so, make the the corrections by following my answer below and kindly mark as answer if it does help you.

Comment: are you still stuck with this?

Comment: What's the delay @Xenon Kfr ? let us know if you're still on this and what the new issue is...

Answer (score 1):

> **Basically, in relations to your code, below are the two layouts you're dealing with, I will label them for reference sake.**
>
> > **x** = **bottom_sheet.xml**

and

> > **y** = **activity_main.xml**

Below is What **x** should look like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="#4A4A4A"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Bottom Sheet Handle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is What y should look like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Things to take note of in **x**:

```
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
```

> Also, in your java code:

```
/*I will advice you test with state_collapsed to be sure you don't start looking for unknown bug when it seem like its not showing.*/
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

// we can still control the behavior from here like below
bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
```

That's it.

Comment: If you set bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false) , you can't hide the bottom sheet. I want to hide it and open it by swiping up.

Comment: Then, set it to true, just telling you what you that you can still change the behaviour when ever you like from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GestureDetector` to detect swiping up gesture ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect)). For instance you could implement your `onFling` callback like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                // Horizontal swipe occurred
            }
            else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                // Vertical swipe occurred
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    // Swipe to bottom
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

   private void onSwipeTop() {
       sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
   }
```

Comment: Why GestureDetector ??? your answer is almost off the question! BottomSheetBehavior is the question.

Comment: GestureDetector is a helper to detect right place to change the sheetBehavior's state while it's out of visible/touchable area

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but it's expensive compare to just fixing the bug in his code!